# Optional action route preg match PHP

Tags: php, router

Example:

```
http://mysite.domain/user1 //profile user 1
http://mysite.domain/user1/photos //photos user 1
http://mysite.domain/user1/friends //friends user 1
```

Action of user only photos or friends.This is my code:

```
if (preg_match('/^\/([\w\-]+)(\/[photos|friends]+)$/i', $url, $m)) {
       //code...
}
```

But not working, somebody can help me?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: Please state what exactly you mean by “not working”. Is the expression matching too little? too much? the wrong things? Also please tell us the exact value of `$url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is `[photos|friends]+`. This will match too broadly, namely any combination of the characters mentioned, including `|`; not the whole string in the order you put it (either `'photos'` or `'profile`').

I think what you want for the expression is `'/^\/([\w\-]+)\/(photos|friends)$/i'` — that’s assuming `$url` is `'/user1/photos'` or `'/user1/friends'`.

I would suggest when matching URLs to use a regex delimiter other than `/`, because having to escape all the slashes makes the expression hard to comprehend. Personally, I like to use the comma (as it’s rather rare in URLs): `',^/([\w\-]+)/(photos|friends)$,i'`.

**Update**

To make the last part (`/photos` or `/friends`) optional, use `',^/([\w\-]+)(/(photos|friends))?$,i'`. If you want to allow `/user1/` (with the trailing slash), you can keep it even simpler `',^/([\w\-]+)/(photos|friends)?$,i'`.

The `?` will make the preceeding token optional (in the first case, this is `(/(photos|friends))`, in the second case, it’s just `(photos|friends)`.

Comment: tks, it working with '/user1/photos' or '/user1/friends', but not working with '/user1'. Plz help me

Comment: awesome, tks so much!